# MongoDB Embedded vs Reference Private info

Tags: design, mongodb, schema

I have searched extensively for a similar Mongo schema design and can't find relevant examples.

I have a store (with public info), each store has an account (with private account info).

```
// store object
{
  name: "Departement Store",
  email: "contact@store.com",
  account: { // private info not returned by API
    manager: "Steve",
    employees: [...]
  }
}
```

The stores will be searched through a public API. I am limiting the search queries using MongoDB's features to limit the returned data:

```
db.stores.find({}, {account:0});
```

**My question**: is it more efficient to keep the private data as a subdocument or in a separate collection? It seems a separate collection with account info is the best choice as I will be picking and choosing from an embedded document.

References:

- [mongo schema (embedding vs reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744966/mongo-schema-embedding-vs-reference)
- [Embedded document vs reference in mongoose design model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302279/embedded-document-vs-reference-in-mongoose-design-model)

Answer (score 1):

As an update, this question was answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/-1eXvkoxHUw

Summary: Keep data in one document, restrict data using MongoDB's built-in projection feature.